# Inside realtime lighting

Tags: unity, lighting

I have a small house with point light in it. But as you see, directional and sky lighting affect inside lighting. It's too bright.

How can I make that inside is only affected by point light and not by directional light. Or maybe just a small amount of directional light.

[image]

Comment: [You might find this earlier question on lighting caves useful](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130185/cave-lighting-in-unity)

Answer (score 1):

You can use layers to control what content is lit by which lights.

[image: Interior-Exterior Lighting Example]

Here I've built a room with two shells of geometry cladding: the exterior shell is in the Default layer, and the interior shell is in a new layer I called Interior.

My red point light's culling mask is set to light only the Interior layer.

My directional sunlight's culling mask is set to light every layer *except* the Interior.

I also edited my scene settings to drop the "Environment Lighting" ambient multiplier to zero, and added a couple of extra directional lights in a soft blue to make up for it. These fill lights also don't light the interior, and don't cast shadows.

Answer (score -2):

I think you might need to see this 16 min video about Unity's lighting.

[LIGHTING in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnG2gOKV9dw) . But the general idea is that your indirect lighting is too strong and you need to tweak the Directional light for indirect lighting as well the global lighting settings.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer how to make interior spaces be lit differently than exterior spaces.