# How to make a sun that only illuminates stuff in sunlight?

Tags: unity, lighting

I set up a scene with Gaia Pro, and it looks really nice so far.  It even has a script to add a Sun object and have it circle the scene, which is pretty cool.

Problem is, it's implemented as a Directional Light, which illuminates everything.  I created a cavern with Digger as a part of the scene, and the interior of the cavern is brightly lit by the sun.  For obvious reasons, this should not happen!

What's the best way to fix the sun so it won't illuminate things that logically wouldn't be in sunlight?

Comment: Is your directional light not set to cast shadows? Shadow casting should block the light where it hits the cavern roof...

Comment: It does cast shadows, but the cavern is still illuminated.  And I can tell that the illumination is coming from the Sun, specifically, because there are shadows in the cavern (not sure what's casting them, maybe the Terrain overhead?) and they move around with the movement of the sun.  I can't help but wonder if it's not Digger being weird somehow; it creates caves using strange voxel-based stuff that isn't the normal Unity way.

Comment: Can you show us screenshots, and walk us through creating a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, so we can reproduce your situation and test potential solutions?

Comment: @DMGregory The screenshots, I can get later on today.  The repro case... that's not so easy when it involves a paid tool that a lot of people seeing this question won't have.

Comment: If the paid asset is required to reproduce this problem, then it might be a customer support issue to take to the developers of that asset. We'll do our best to help with the details you're able to provide (say, inspecting the renderers produced/modified by Digger to see if we can work out why they're not casting shadows as expected)

Comment: [You may also find this previous Q&A on cavern lighting in Unity applicable](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/130185/39518)